# rsync thinks the source host is a command

Tags: ssh, rsync, file-copy

So I was trying to download a file from a remote host connected with SSH to a local folder on my Mac using `rsync`. The command I used is:

```
$ rsync --progress -avz -e "ssh root@1.2.3.4 -i ~/.ssh/keyFile" root@1.2.3.4:/path/to/files/ ~/Downloads/
```

And here is what is prompted:

```
root@1.2.3.4's password: [I typed the password here]
bash: 1.2.3.4: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

It seems odd that the remote host address `1.2.3.4` is interpreted as a command?! I am not sure how and why this happens. How could I update the command to achieve expected result and start to copy the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you don't want to include the user@host part of the ssh command within the -e flag.  Try

```
rsync --progress -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyFile" root@1.2.3.4:/path/to/files/ ~/Downloads/
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ssh` command, when used with the `-e` (or `--rsh`) option in `rsync`, should not need to mention the remote host by name as this is part of the source specification (in your command).

In your case, it would be enough to use

```
rsync --progress -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyFile" root@1.2.3.4:/path/to/files/ ~/Downloads/
```

`rsync` will execute the command given in `-e` together with the source path.  You can see the exact command being executed if you use yet another `-v`.  It will most likely look something like

```
opening connection using: ssh -i "~/.ssh/keyFile" root@1.2.3.4 -l root 1.2.3.4 rsync --server --sender -vvlogDtpre.iLfxC . /path/to/files/
```

Here, you can see that `1.2.3.4` would be interpreted as a command to be executed on the remote host as user `root` (taking the *actual* command that ought to be executed as command line arguments).

`rsync` starts a "sender" on the source side of the file copy, and a "receiver" on the destination side.  These two processes are then communicating the actual data and checksums etc. between each other to carry out the file copy. The `ssh` command that you see above is the command that `rsync` uses to (try to) start the sender on the remote host. The `--server --sender` etc. are internal command line flags that `rsync` uses for this purpose. The `rsync` manual basically says "don't use these options yourself".

In your case, you can see in the error message that the receiver (`rsync` running locally) is having problems communicating with the sender on the remote host.  This is because the sender wasn't started correctly, and this in turn was due to the erroneous `ssh` command.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But could you elaborate a little on the second command in your post? Is it a pseudo-command? And what is `-vvlogDtpre.iLfxC`?

Comment: @jackxujh `rsync` starts a "sender" on the source side of the file copy, and a "receiver" on the destination side. The `ssh` command that you see is the command that `rsync` uses to start the sender on the remote host. The `--server --sender` etc. are internal command line flags that `rsync` uses for this purpose.  The `rsync` manual basically says "don't use these options yourself".

Comment: so do you mean that if I use `-vv` with `rsync`, I will see that line of prompt? Like some sort of expanded prompt?

Comment: @jackxujh If you use `-vv` then `rsync` will tell you more verbosely what it is doing, including how it tries to connect to the other host, yes. And even more verbosely with `-vvv`.

Comment: Oh, I got it! The more `v` I use, the more detailed the log or prompt I get.